# Aptana Studio 3 Automatically sync doesen't work with new files/folders

Tags: aptana, setup-deployment, aptana3

I've set "Automatically sync my changes with the remote site" to "Automatically sync from my machine to the remote site" with an SFTP connection.
The problem is that the sync doesn't work if:
- I create a new file/folder
- I delete a file/folder
- I rename a file/folder

To workaround this bug I need to start manual Deploy :(

Comment: Hi, are you asking a question or you are answering your own question?

Comment: Yeah, the functionality is for automatically upload any changes to the local file when you save in the editor.  For what you suggested, you could file a ticket at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD.